# Empathy Notifications ? How open Emphaty from envelope?

Tags: empathy, default, default-programs

Well no, was no similar question. Ok somebody start to chat me, I got envelope. When I click on it Telepathy not Empathy opens, always. Well Empathy looks better and has nicer UI. How to make Empathy opening from envelope ? Thanks if there is solution to this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess I resolved this problem :) But by using Kopete instead of Empathy :) With Kopete it all works perfect :)